# Windows 10 tablet hibernates too quickly, rather than sleeping

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

Ever since the Anniversary update of Windows 10, both my Surface Pro 3 and my Dell Venue 8 Pro have really aggressive power management settings.

If I have the devices running on battery, they go into deep hibernation after about an hour. To use them again I have to hold the power button and wait for the device to boot up again.

This never used to happen, they'd simply go to sleep and pressing the power button woke them up immediately, like you'd expect a tablet to do. Now they both seem to work more like a laptop where the device hibernates and turns off completely.

It's great for saving battery power, but destroys the instant usability of them.

I've gone into the power settings and adjusted the "Hibernate after" settings, but it's as if that setting is being ignored. Are there any other settings that need altering?

Comment: Have you verified if any firmware updates have been released and/or verified if hybrid hibernation is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd.exe with administrator status,
then type:

```
powercfg /hibernate off
```

(You can undo that by `powercfg /hibernate on`)

This completely disables any automatic hibernation.

I had exactly the same problems as you described with my Venue 8 pro (5855) and now it seems to work fine again. Standby works properly, with instant wakeup. And no more annoying bootup, when you left the tablet alone for a while.

Comment: IMHO, this is a *very* bad idea in battery-powered devices. Your work would be lost because the PC will either shut down or just turn off.